# Use TreeView to display hierarchical structure with context-sensitive contexts in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I'd like to "translate" my earlier Forms-Application into an WPF Solution trying to follow the MVVM-Pattern.

Now I'm facing the problem that I want to build a "context-senstive" Contextmenu - and I have no idea how to start.

This is the Code from the Forms-Application to generate the hierarchical structure and the Contextmenus:

```
_tvLocation.Nodes.Clear();
        foreach (Data.Location location in LocationManager.GetAll(this.DataSource)) {
            TreeNode parent = new TreeNode(location.Name) {
                Tag = location,
                ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(new MenuItem[] { 
                    new MenuItem("Standort löschen", new EventHandler(DelLocation_Click)) { 
                        Tag = location
                    }, 
                    new MenuItem("Raum hinzufügen", new EventHandler(AddRoom_Click)) {
                        Tag = location
                    }
                })
            };
            foreach (Data.Room room in location.GetChildren(DataSource)) {
                TreeNode child = new TreeNode(room.Name) {
                    Tag = room,
                    ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(new MenuItem[]{
                        new MenuItem("Raum löschen", new EventHandler(DelRoom_Click)){
                            Tag = room
                        },
                        new MenuItem("Schrank hinzufügen", new EventHandler(AddLocker_Click)){
                            Tag = room
                        }
                    })
                };
                foreach (Data.Locker locker in room.GetChildren(this.DataSource)) {
                    TreeNode gradChild = new TreeNode(locker.Name) {
                        Tag = locker,
                        ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(new MenuItem[]{
                        new MenuItem("Schrank löschen", new EventHandler(DelLocker_Click)){
                            Tag = locker
                        }
                    })
                    };
                    child.Nodes.Add(gradChild);
                }
                parent.Nodes.Add(child);
            }
            _tvLocation.Nodes.Add(parent);
        }
        _tvLocation.ExpandAll();
```

Is there a way to build something like that in WPF? (Sure there is - can anyone give me a hint?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe (almost?) everything you can do in WinForms is possible with WPF. Please look at some tutorials related to Treeview and HierarchicalDataTemplate. Here are a couple that are useful - [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx) and [here](http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/blogs/How-to-get-a-treeview-item-node-value-using-a-ContextMenu-using-WPF-and-C-sharp.aspx)

Comment: Ty, I already solved the display-part - now I'm on the Command-part. And of course everything you can do in Forms is possible in WPF - and more.

Comment: I thought the second link I gave had an example with a ContextMenu... I will try to understand the question again.

Comment: It's okay, I'll set the question to solved - Obviously I was too fast asking the question here, I found some pretty good tutorials explaining how to create commands and bind them to the View. Thanks anyway!